# How to connect local and remote Mercurial repos?

Tags: linux, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Typically, in Mercurial, I create a new project by:

1. Create a new remote repo
2. Clone the repo locally
3. Make changes to the local repo
4. Push those changes to the remote repo

The "remote repo" here is actually our "central/originating" DVCS server (`http://ourhg.ourorg.example.com`, etc.).

I am now in a situation where I had to use a code generation tool to produce the source code for a simple web app. So the source code exists *before* the remote repo exists on our hg server. I'm looking for the exact shell commands I need to execute to get this properly pushed to the remote repo.

I *believe* it should be something like this:

1. Use the code generator to generate the code, say, at `/home/myuser/myapp`.
2. Initialize an hg repo for `myapp` locally on my machine (`hg init`)
3. Add the generated source code for `myapp` to this local repo (`hg add`, then `hg commit`)
4. On `ourhg.ourorg.example.com`, create the new remote repo (manual steps)
5. **???**
6. Push the changes sitting in my local repo to the remote repo (`hg push`)

I *know* there is something missing in between Step #4 (creation of the remote repo) and Step #6 (pushing to the remote repo). There surely needs to be some "connection" step where my local repo and the remote repo realize they represent the same project/source code/etc. This is my hangup here, so I ask: **what is Step #5**?

Comment: Google "man hgrc", and look into section "paths". E.g `default = http://username@ourhg.ourorg.example.com/reponame`

Comment: @danielkullmann - everybody can `hg push URL` instead of `hg push ALIAS`

Comment: @LazyBadger yes, you don't have to,  but you probably will do it to save yourself from having to type the whole URL all the time..

Comment: @danielkullmann - it can be step 7-8, skeleton-creation **is** automated|scripted work

Answer (score 1):

> what is Step #5?

Discover URL of this repo. Because it's empty repo, you can don't worry about "related|unrelated"

Comment: Thanks @LazyBadger (+1) - but your answer is a little cryptic! What do you mean when you say "discover" the URL of the remote repo? What does that entail? Also, I'm not following you when you say "*...don't worry about 'related|unrelated'.*" - can you elaborate? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja - 1. "discover URL" means (as written) - you must to know URL of repote repo in order to be able to communicate with it 2. Related|unrelated repo plays, qhen you'll visualize repo-tree - if|when remote repo (with some content) doesn't share common history with local you'll get two separate tree instead of increased one

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badger (+1 again) - so am I correct in stating that in my case there really isn't a "Step #5"? I can just go from Step #4 (creating the remote repo) to doing an `hg push http://myuser@ourhg.ourorg.example.com/newRepo`? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja - yes, you can push this way

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you need to do to associate them.  You can do `hg push URL_OF_REMOTE` on your local and it will work.  If you don't want to have to provide the URL each time you can edit (creating if necessary) `.hg/hgrc` in the repo and set the `default=` value in the `[paths]` section.  Something like this

```
[paths]
default=URL_OF_REMOTE
```

That's optional though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your origial steps, with caveat:

1. Create a new remote repo
2. Clone the repo locally (this will set default path of local to remote).
3. Make changes to the local repo (Use the code generator app to generate the code in the local repo).
4. Push those changes to the remote repo.

With this flow, you don't have to manually update the path to the remote repo.